# Cursor stuck on title bar with double monitor

Tags: screen, monitor, cursor

I just bought a second monitor to use with my laptop, a vertical one. Aside from the difference in dpi, which I can live with (not easily fixed unless i blur the screen with xrandr scaling), my cursor gets stuck on the titlebar when trying to go from one screen to another. If the cursor passes the title bar, I can see its tail on the other screen but i have to go down a bit to go through. It's like a little hook, really annoying. The other screen is taller and I have to cross this spot a lot.

I don't even know how to describe this problem to google. Anyone got an idea to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Go to "Activities" and search for "Display"
Align the monitors if possible (I do not have Gnome nor 2 monitors- so thats a guess)
If "Gnome" does not provide you with a decent interface to align your monitors try to install **arandr**:

`sudo apt install arandr`

Open a terminal or start "arandr" via the "Activities" search button...

More information can be found in this exhaustive forum:
[How to change monitor position/navigation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10703/how-to-change-monitor-position-navigation)

Comment: I have already aligned them in the middle, where they're physically located. I can cross this spot from the right (2nd, vertical screen) to left, but not from left to right

Comment: Then you need to switch the monitors (in aranr, not physicially) Could you post a screenshot of your monitor layout? (with arandr)